# Append current date to the filename via Cron?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I've created a Cron task at my webhost to daily backup my database and I would like it to append the current date to the filename.

My Cron job looks like this

```
mysqldump -u username -pPassword db_name > www/db_backup/db_backup+date%d%m%y.sql
```

But the file I get is this: **db_backup+date** no file extension or date.

I've also tried this command

```
mysqldump -u username -pPassword db_name > www/db_backup/db_backup_'date +%d%m%y'.sql
```

but that doesn't even give an file output.

What is the right syntax for getting the date appended to my file??

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
* * * * * echo "hello" > /tmp/helloFile_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).txt
```

You just need to escape the percent signs.

Other date formats:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/

Comment: Working on CentOS 6.6. 

*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/script.php > cron-job-log-$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).txt

Comment: The @ursuleacv answers works as expected. Here is my sample cron command: `08 10 * * * mysqldump -uYeBeSis_X2 -pPASWORDTHING dbName > /var/www/yebesis/mysqly/$(date +\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%I_\%M_\%p)_yebesis.sql`

Comment: I guess he meant "escape percentages" because parentheses aren't escaped. After I escaped the percentage symbols it worked in my cron.

Comment: Note to self: BSD's `date` doesn't support the very convenient `-I`

Comment: Is it possible to set date to env variable to prevent writing it twice(for stdout and stderr)? both $() and backtikcs failed.

Comment: @quant2016 probably.  In cronie (which RHEL uses), I regularly do things like this on our "common management server: `Srv=foo; scripts/dosomething.sh $Srv &> cronlogs/$Srv/foo.log`.

Comment: Escaping the `%` chars is what I missed.

Answer (score 32):

You should use ``` `` ``` instead of `''` around the command you want to execute to generate the current date for your filename.

Comment: could you edit the answer or someone provide a more exact example in the comments?

Comment: ```> proposed_file_name_`date + \%d\%m\%y`.sql```

Answer (score 10):

You must escape the format and use evaluation

```
mysqldump -u username -pPassword db_name > www/db_backup/db_backup_`date +\%d\%m\%y`.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

I need to create a new log file every time command is executed. So every day I should have a log like this `/home/me/Logs/power_20151230.log`
The `crontab` line that I use is this:

```
00 8 * * * /home/me/power.py ON >> /home/me/Logs/power\_`date +20\%y\%m\%d`
```

**Note** the underscore character must be escaped too.

Comment: It's not necessary to prepend `20` in front of `\%y`. It's better to use the upper-cased Y like this: `\%Y`.