# How can cron output to a new log file based on date?

Tags: php, cron, file-permissions

I'd like to log cron output to a dated file — `/tmp/log/cron-2014-12-17.log`

```
$ mkdir /tmp/log
$ chmod 777 /tmp/log
$ ls -lah /tmp/log
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 .
```

Cron (via `root` user)

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php > /tmp/log/cron-$(date "+%F").log 2>&1
```

`/tmp/log` remains empty after each minute.

If I run the script manually from command line a log file is created, and output is as expected.

```
// Running it manually as a CLI works fine, but not as a cron
$ /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php > /tmp/log/cron-$(date "+%F").log 2>&1
```

Also, if I create a file and chmod 777 it, the cron *will* write output to this created file. It just won't create one on the fly.

```
// Let's create it first
$ touch /tmp/log/cron.log
$ chmod 777 /tmp/log/cron.log
// wait for the next minute...
$ tail -f /tmp/log/cron.log
output... output... output...
```

But this doesn't work for dynamic names like `/tmp/log/cron-2014-12-17.log`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append current date to the filename via Cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9110663/608639), [Sending cron output to a file with a timestamp in its name](https://serverfault.com/q/117360), [How to add the logs to a crontab with time stamp](https://askubuntu.com/q/391542), [How to log cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811738/608639), etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will fix your issue:

```
0 0 * * * /some/path/to/a/file.php >> /tmp/log/cron-`date +\%F`.log 2>&1
```