# Crontab job output to file

Tags: linux, bash, cron

in my crontab i have this

```
* * * * * /users/abcd/runme.sh >> /mnt/ansible/logs/runme.log
```

is it possible to append the date to the file with something like this? I've tried several different variations with no luck.

```
* * * * * /users/abcd/runme.sh >> /mnt/ansible/logs/runme_`date +%F`.log
```

Comment: `echo "hello" > runme_$(date +%F).log`  Works for me on the command line, but perhaps because this is coming through cron, you may need to specify the full path to `date` like: `echo "hello" > runme_$(/bin/date +%F).log`

Comment: @JNevill for now my issue seems to be formatting. im getting messages from cron like this "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append current date to the filename via Cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9110663/608639), [Sending cron output to a file with a timestamp in its name](https://serverfault.com/q/117360), [How to add the logs to a crontab with time stamp](https://askubuntu.com/q/391542), [How can cron output to a new log file based on date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27539083/608639), [How to log cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811738/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Always works. `* * * * * /users/abcd/runme.sh >> /mnt/ansible/logs/runme_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).log`

That will work.

Comment: You should correct your date arguments.  It should be `%Y%m%d%H%M`.  Capital M is for minutes, small m is for the month.

Comment: not work for me.